# Unable to generate the token to send an email using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

1. package com.example.GraphMS_API.service;

   import java.util.Arrays;

   import com.azure.identity.UsernamePasswordCredential; import
   com.azure.identity.UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder; import
   com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
   import com.microsoft.graph.models.User; import
   com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;

   public class App {

   ```
   public static void main(final String args[]) {

       final UsernamePasswordCredential usernamePasswordCredential = new
   ```

   UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder()
   .clientId("dfdfjhf").username("abc@xyz.com")
   .password("1234").build();

   ```
       final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider =
   ```

   new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
   Arrays.asList("Mail.ReadWrite.Shared"), usernamePasswordCredential);        final GraphServiceClient graphClient
   = GraphServiceClient.builder()
   .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider).buildClient();

   ```
       final User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
       System.out.println(me.companyName);

   } }
   ```

Comment: Please add code in the question so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried isolating the issue from code and leveraging Postman/Graph Explorer to make same API call. Observe the behavior and see if you are able to obtain token.
Also make sure SDK you are trying to use is latest and updated.

Thanks!

Comment: I did it with graph explorer and it works, but I am struggling with the access token, currently I am not able to generate the access token

Comment: Please refer to this tutorial to build java apps using Microsoft graph - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java . Also make sure SDK is latest and updated. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/java